# Trocar Html.Action() por uma requisição Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp

Tenho um método que retorna uma `ActionResult` chamado através de um `Html.Action()` diretamente na `View` usando `Razor`.

Este método é usado para renderizar um `ComboBox` da `devExpress` com os dados que envio de um comando `SQL` na abertura da `view`, onde leva-se muito tempo para carregar os `combobox` da tela, uma vez que para cada 1 ele deve ir no banco e trazer os dados do comando passado.

**Problema**
Eu quero trocar essa chamada através do `Html.Action()` para um `javascript` para que ele faça o carregamento dos dados do `combobox` no evento de clique do componente, pra que eu não perca o tempo de carregamento da `view` e carregue só quando o usuário for realmente usar/clicar.

View:

```js
@Html.Action("ComboBoxDataFilter", "SearchComboBox", new
        {
          controlName = "ComboBoxFILIAL",
          sql = "SELECT CODFIL, TAG, RAZSOC FROM FILIAL",
          fkField = "CODFIL",
          fields = "TAG, RAZSOC",
          descriptionFields = "Código, Razão Social",
          widthColumns = "30%,70%",
          width = "100%",
          showFormatString = true,
          showAdvancedFilter = false,
          showStandardFilter = false,
          showDropDownButton = true,
          inputHidden = "CODFIL",
          filter = "",
          eventSelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e) { $('#CODFIL').val(ComboBoxFILIAL.GetValue()); onCodFilChange(); }",
          eventBeginCallback = "",
          filterfield = "RAZSOC",
          value = (Model == null || Model.CODFIL == null) ? 0 : Model.CODFIL
        })
```

```js
public ActionResult ComboBoxDataFilter(string controlName, string sql, string fkField, string customFkField, string fields, string filter, string eventSelectedIndexChanged, string eventValueChanged, string eventBeginCallback, string eventEndCallback, string value, string sqlValue, string filterfield, string descriptionFields, string fkTable, string compositeFk, string displayFields, string inputHidden, string width, string widthColumns, bool showAdvancedFilter, bool showStandardFilter, bool showDropDownButton, bool showFormatString, string valueType, bool readOnly,  string view, Dictionary<string, object> parametros, bool showCleanButton = true)
{
  var model;
  return PartialView("SearchComboBoxFilter", model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso, cria um objeto que que recebe todas configurações do seu combobox e depois manda via post.

```js
             var config ={
                    controlName = "ComboBoxFILIAL",
                      sql = "SELECT CODFIL, TAG, RAZSOC FROM FILIAL",
                      fkField = "CODFIL",
                      fields = "TAG, RAZSOC",
                      descriptionFields = "Código, Razão Social",
                      widthColumns = "30%,70%",
                      width = "100%",
                      showFormatString = true,
                      showAdvancedFilter = false,
                      showStandardFilter = false,
                      showDropDownButton = true,
                      inputHidden = "CODFIL",
                      filter = "",
                    eventBeginCallback = "",
                      filterfield = "RAZSOC",
             }


               $.ajax()({
                    url: "/ComboBoxDataFilter/SearchComboBox",
                    type: "POST",
        data: config ,
                    dataType: "json"
                });
```

```
public ActionResult ComboBoxDataFilter(ComboBoxDataFilter config)
{

  JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var model = ser.Deserialize<ComboBoxDataFilter>(config);

  return PartialView("SearchComboBoxFilter", model);
}
```